# With WebApi 2.1 am I always required to decorate methods with [HttpGet] , put etc.?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following action method that I am calling with a GET:

```
[Route("Retrieve/{cityStatusId:int}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Retrieve(int cityStatusId) {

}
```

When I call this I am getting the message:

```
message=The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
```

With WebAPI 2.1 do I still have to decorate all my methods with [HttpGet]. I had thought this was no longer a requirement?

Comment: The convention is your action name starts with the HTTP verb. Try re-naming your action Get instead of Retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the method with the prefix "Get",

e.g.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCityStatus(int cityStatusId) {}
```